# Radius of circle given 3 points in polar coordinates

Tags: circles, polar-coordinates

So I've found how to construct a circle passing through 3 points in cartesian coordinates using [this](http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Circle3D.htm) website. Is there an easier way of doing this using polar coordinates, or is the best way to solve it by converting the points to cartesian coordinates? The only thing I need to know is if these 3 points could all be fit within a circle of radius r.

Comment: $$R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}$$ where the side lengths $a,b,c$ can be computed from the Pythagorean theorem and $\Delta$ can be computed from Heron's formula or the shoelace formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cartesian coordinates and no matrix calculations, it is quite simple.

$$(x_1-a)^2+(y_1-b)^2=r^2 \tag 1$$
$$(x_2-a)^2+(y_2-b)^2=r^2 \tag 2$$
$$(x_3-a)^2+(y_3-b)^2=r^2 \tag 3$$

Subtract $(1)$ for $(2)$ and $(3)$ to get
$$2a(x_1-x_2)+2b(y_1-y_2)=(x_1^2+y_1^2)-(x_2^2+y_2^2) \tag 4$$
$$2a(x_1-x_3)+2b(y_1-y_3)=(x_1^2+y_1^2)-(x_3^2+y_3^2) \tag 5$$

So, two linear equations in $a$ and $b$; easy to solve. When you have them, plug in any of $(1)$, $(2)$ or $(3)$ to get $r^2$ then $r$.

Comment: That's wonderful, thank you very much!